# Display output in GUI interface after checking the contents of the dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, matlab-guide

I am creating a GUI interface that takes input from the user.
first, the weight.
second, the speed.

Then, I want to do some calculations based on these inputs.
first, acceleration, which is shown in the script below as the first function I defined.
second, force, which I utilised the weight input to multiply with the acceleration function.

mostly, I have done the interface already, but I cannot test the functions is they will be working properly, unless I have compare the calculated values to the dictionary contents.

let's say, I have a default dict information, as shown below.

Grade 1: A
Force: 500

Grade 2: B
Force: 300

Grade 3: C
Force:100

THE PROBLEM:

If for example, I entered, 50 for weight and 100 for speed, and hit the button, the program should automatically calculate the force based on these inputs.

If for example, the calculated force was 250...that value falls in Grade 2: B in the default dictionary.
(how can I go to the default dictionary and check those, loop through all the values of the keys in there, until my program decides that the value actually falls in this grade?)

then, the GUI should print the final output in the interface, in this case, it the GRADE 2: B.

How can I add these in my script below?
any hint would be much appreciated. This is an assignment but if you don't want to give the real code, I understand and that's fair enough. I just want to know where to start, look at, and how to understand the codes.

So please, I'd be happy if you could help.

here's what I have done so far.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

x = []
def cal_acceleration(*args):
    try:
        # 1/2 and 0.4 default value, get the velocity value 
        # from below then multiplied by 1/2.
        acce=((1/2) * ve.get()) / 0.40 
        x.append(acce)
    except ValueError:
        pass

def cal_force(*args):
    try:
        # multiplied the output of this function to the above function.
        force=ma.get() * x
    except ValueError:
        pass
"""Creating a GUI with the following interface."""
root = Tk()
root.title("what type?")

frame = ttk.Frame(root, padding="5 5 5 5")
frame.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N,S,E,W)) # stick frame to center.

ma = StringVar() # allocate user input weight
v = StringVar() # allocate user input speed

ma_entry = ttk.Entry(frame, width=7,textvariable=m) # entry dialogue for weight
ma_entry.grid(column=1,row=0,sticky=(W,E))

ve_entry = ttk.Entry(frame, width=7, textvariable=v) # entry dialogue for speed
ve_entry.grid(column=1,row=1,sticky=(W,E))

ma_label = ttk.Label(frame, text="how heavy:") # labelling weight
ma_label.grid(column=0, row=0,sticky=E)

velo_label = ttk.Label(frame, text="speed:") # labelling speed
velo_label.grid(column=0, row=1,sticky=E)

# setting the button for GUI. combining two functions using lambda.
find_button = ttk.Button(frame, text="Find", command=lambda[cal_acceleration(),cal_force()])
find_button.grid(column=2,row=0,sticky=W)

root.mainloop()
```

thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The first step would be to fix your existing code.
As it is right now, it is not working for several reasons explained below, which leads me to think you have not tested it (recently).

Lambda call does not have ":" to it, preventing from calling your functions.

Check for your variable names, is it "v" or "ve" and is it "m" or "ma" ?

### Debug your calculating function to work (it doesn't).

hint: your data must be the right type. you have Int, it wants Float.

hint: do you think multiplying a list works?

Then have it print your data first. When you know it's the result you expected, then you can start working on displaying in the gui.